# Even number of successes in n independent Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Hi I am working on the exercise about the probability of even number of successes in n independent Bernoulli trials, with probability $p$ of success in single trial. I know that the right answer is:
$$\frac{1 + (1 - 2p)^n}{2}$$
I am curious what is wrong with the approach of summing up probabilities of all possible values of even successes. Let A denote the event of obtaining even number of successes in n trials, then:
$$P(A) = \sum_{i = 2}^{i \le 2n}\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$
So for example for $n = 5, p = 1/2$ we get:
$$P(A) = \binom{5}{2}(\frac{1}{2})^2*(\frac{1}{2})^{3} + \binom{5}{4}(\frac{1}{2})^4*(\frac{1}{2})^{1} = 0.46875$$
Which is clearly wrong since from the above formula it should equal:
$$\frac{1 + (1 - 2(\frac{1}{2
}))^5}{2} = 0.5$$

Comment: $0$ is an even number.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Thanks for the clarification :)